# How can I remove an image from my django-cms?

Tags: django-cms

I uploaded an image into the editor and I am getting an error:
TemplateSyntaxError at /en/ 
'thumbnail' tag received a bad argument: 'crop'
I think the image is too big, but I can't enter the editor to remove it.  Should I do this in the database?  How would I do that without breaking things worse?

I can't currently enter the editor without getting the error.

Comment: If there's something saved to the database that's causing problems, deleting straight from the db could work. But what's the stack trace? Post some code & the error so that a proper solution might be found.

Comment: Thanks @markwalker_. 
The traceback is here.  As it is django-cms code, I'm not very familiar with it.
https://dpaste.de/WCUM

Answer (score -1):

As a variant, for solving this problem, you have to remove the validation of the parameters in the plugin. I will give more information, if I have a look at your code. Can be everything.

Comment: please, answer only well-asked questions, otherwise, if it's possible, use comments to clarify the question

Comment: @amankkg - how would you recommend that I clarify the question?  Something got put into the system (django-cms) that doesn't allow re-entering the django-cms editor to remove it.  No more editing of the cms of the website is possible because of this error.  How can I remove the offending image to regain functionality?

Comment: @RandO Not sure I can... maybe add a link to error logs in the question body. Originally, my comment is to this particular answer and its helpfulness, not to your question.